# Polyglossia fills the aux file with useless code

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, auxiliary-files

My file uses polyglossia with English, Hebrew and Arabic languages. The aux file is filled with 2,103 (!!) instances of the following code:

```
\selectlanguage *[variant=usmax]{english}
\@writefile{toc}{\selectlanguage *[variant=usmax]{english}}
\@writefile{lof}{\selectlanguage *[variant=usmax]{english}}
\@writefile{lot}{\selectlanguage *[variant=usmax]{english}}
\bgroup 
\@writefile{toc}{\bgroup }
\@writefile{lof}{\bgroup }
\@writefile{lot}{\bgroup }
\selectlanguage *{hebrew}
\@writefile{toc}{\selectlanguage *{hebrew}}
\@writefile{lof}{\selectlanguage *{hebrew}}
\@writefile{lot}{\selectlanguage *{hebrew}}
\egroup
```

That makes an aux file of 1.2 MB, which takes 10-15 seconds to be read by XeTeX and then as much to be written anew.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong because it is the first time I encounter this problem, but what? Any idea of what I may be doing wrong?

My versions are: XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021), polyglossia 2021/04/12 v1.53.

Comment: well the \bgroup is imho no longer done by polyglossia, but apart from this: it tries to keep track of language changes also in the auxiliary files and you seem to switch between languages a lot.

Comment: It mostly depends on how you change language. Any `\selectlanguage` or `\begin{otherlanguage}` would produce those lines in the `.aux` file, while `\begin{otherlanguage*}` or `\foreignlanguage` wouldn't. Without a simple example it's not easy to give advice.

Comment: That's a great advice! By using `\begin{otherlanguage*}{hebrew}` execution time went down from 1 minute to 12 seconds and the AUX file from 1.2MB to 7.5kB. Thanks!